# Changing form action method name but server reffering to old method name

Tags: java, html, servlets

I'm using Eclipse Indigo. In my HTML form action method I put `<form action="T1" method="post">` where T1 is a Java servlet. If I edit and rename form action method to T2 and save changes, when running tomcat server on localhost, after clicking on button it still goes to T1!

I tried refreshing my project, deleting and recreating server but still the same problem. What should I do?

Any help is appreciated.

My web.xml file:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

This is my html file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
     <body>
    <form action="Pk" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="tex1"> <br> 
    Address <input type="text" name="tex2"> <br>
      College Name <input type="text" name="tex3"> <br>
    Aggregate percentage <input type="text" name="tex4"> <br>
      Title of Resume <input type="text" name="tex5"> <br>
        Username <input type="text" name="tex6"> <br>
       Password <input type="password" name="tex7"> <br>
     <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Login"> <br>
      </form>
      </body>
       </html>
```

And this is servlet file:

```
      public class Pk extends HttpServlet {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       String name="",addr="",coll="", aggper="", tor="", user="", pass="";
       public Pk() {
         super();


 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();


    name=(String)request.getParameter("tex1");
    addr=(String)request.getParameter("tex2");

    coll=(String)request.getParameter("tex3");

    aggper=(String)request.getParameter("tex4");

    tor=(String)request.getParameter("tex5");
    user =(String)request.getParameter("tex6");
    pass =(String)request.getParameter("tex7");


    System.out.println("Reached after fetching values");
    if(user.equals("")||pass.equals("")||user.equals(null)||pass.equals(null))
    {
        out.println("Username or Password cannot be blank.");
    }
    else
        {
        System.out.println("Reached in else condition");
        Pk2 reg=new Pk2();
        reg.Registration(name,addr,coll,aggper,tor,user, pass);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
    rd.forward(request, response);
        }
}

}
```

Comment: try clean build..   `project>clean`

Comment: If it does not work even after clean build please upload some code so taht people can understand the issue better and faster

Comment: Any chance to see mapping of your servlets?

Comment: tried project>clean ,still getting 404 error

Answer (score 0):

The previous time I faced the same issue was because of the browser caching the webpage. Can you please clear history or try the same in Private Mode of the browser(or Chrome Incognito mode). You can also verify the source code of the webpage by using firebug utility or chrome's own utility by pressing F12 button in Chrome.

PS - I could have mentioned this in a comment, but I don't have enough Stackoverflow reputation to comment on this post.

Comment: ive tried project>clean, also tried tomcat server>clean>publish ,and also project>refresh, still getting same 404 error

Comment: im not using any mapping, using default web.xml deployment descriptor

Comment: So are you using annotations to configure urlpattern and servlet name? You need to provide a  servlet name to your servlet Pk. Are you providing those details? If not, then please google a working servlet example

Comment: yes i used annotations for servlet file as @WebServlet("/Pk")   still getting 404 error

Comment: Please tell when you are getting this 404 error? Are you getting this error upon clicking login button or when loading the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed finally,problem was with my annotation itself,hence page was not loading after clicking login button.Also after making changes to html/servlet file and refreshing and cleaning project, i still used to get 404 error, but then realized problem was with browser caching the page.So cleared cache and voila!
And thanks everyone for all the help